# iTextSharp not functioning in Winforms project

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

## Environment

C# 2008 Express Edition, Windows Forms, iTextSharp 5.4.0.

I placed the iTextSharp.dll in my projects `bin` folder, I added a reference to it in my project, I have the namespace `using iTextSharp`, `iTextSharp.text` and `iTextSharp.text.pdf` and I've tried the following pieces of code, but nothing is created and no error messages.

Here is the first block:

```
Document doc1 = new Document();
string path = "C:/Temp/Testing";
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(path + "first.pdf", FileMode.Create));
doc1.Open();
doc1.Add(new Paragraph("Test"));
doc1.Close();
```

and here is the second block:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Temp\\Testing" + "Test.pdf", FileMode.Create);
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello"));
doc.Close();
writer.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Try your code on any other drive except C.

Comment: You are probably looking for the file c:\Temp\Testing\Test.pdf.  Filename appears to be saving to C:\Temp\TestingTest.pdf"

Comment: Adding \\ at the end of C:\\Temp\\Testing did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This example open a dialog and the user can save the file. Convert the VB code to C# with a code converter.

```
Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
Using doc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4)
Using w As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)

Dim FileName As String = "Name.pdf"


Here create your document end close it

Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= " & FileName)
Response.Buffer = True
Response.Clear()
Dim bytes = ms.ToArray()
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
Response.OutputStream.Flush()


End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I 've converted it and added using System.Web.UI but Response is unregognized. This is for windows forms not web.